# Can't compile internal constructor call cause:Primary constructor call expected

Tags: constructor, kotlin, compilation

Assume we have the following primary and secondary constructors:

```
open class Animal(val name:String){
  internal constructor(message:InputStream): this(readName(message))
}
```

Why is not possible to call the internal constructor of the super class?

```
class Dog(name:String):Animal(name){
   internal constructor(message:InputStream):super(message)
                                             ^^^^^
                                             Primary constructor call expected
}
```

---

edit

Obviously it compiles when the primary constructor is converted to a secondary constructor or removed at all.

```
class Dog:Animal{
   constructor(name:String):super(name)
   internal constructor(message:InputStream):super(message)

}
```

Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Are these classes in the same module?

Comment: Yes they are the same module!

Comment: @Chriss answering the question from your edit. This is not a compiler bug. This is how the language was designed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html):

> If the class has a primary constructor, each secondary constructor needs to delegate to the primary constructor, either directly or indirectly through another secondary constructor(s). Delegation to another constructor of the same class is done using the `this` keyword

and:

> If the class has no primary constructor, then each secondary constructor has to initialize the base type using the `super` keyword, or to delegate to another constructor which does that.

---

Your `Dog` class has a primary constructor, so you have to delegate to that using `this`.
If you remove the primary constructor, you will be able to refer to `super` constructor:

```
class Dog : Animal {
    constructor(message: InputStream) : super(message)
}
```

(*the above raises no error*)

Comment: Feels like a bug in the lang-spec, one should not be forced to remove the primary constructor.

Comment: I think Kotlin devs just decided to do that, so your inheritance is cleaner. They essentially made sure that you do not mix `this` and `super` in constructors, which could become confusing in big classes.